# Kubernetes loki-stack - Can't get grafana NodePort service to work

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana

In the past I've generally used Kubernetes directly from its own configuration files. I've only recently started to use Helm, in this case to add Loki & Grafana to my cluster. I've followed a tutorial and set up the grafana/loki-stack helm chart with these values:

```
loki:
  enabled: true
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    size: 5Gi

promtail:
  enabled: true

grafana:
  enabled: true
  sidecar:
    datasources:
      enabled: true
  image:
    tag: 8.1.6
```

Then I run:

```
kubectl -n monitoring port-forward service/loki-stack-grafana 30007:80
```

And voila, Grafana is accessible at http://localhost:30007 and everything works.

Now I'm trying to modify the Helm chart to expose a NodePort service, because I don't want to explicitly run a port forwarding command whenever I want to use Grafana. To do this, I've changed my helm chart values to this:

```
loki:
  enabled: true
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    size: 5Gi

promtail:
  enabled: true

grafana:
  enabled: true
  sidecar:
    datasources:
      enabled: true
  image:
    tag: 8.1.6
  service:
    enabled: true
    type: NodePort
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30007
```

When I apply it, the kubernetes console appears to show that I now have a correctly configured NodePort service:

```
loki-stack-grafana    NodePort    10.152.183.19    <none>        80:30007/TCP
```

However, if I try to navigate to http://localhost:3007, I get connection refused.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've used plenty of NodePort services in the past without any issue, and they're all still working.

PS. The loki-stack-grafana service is under a non-default namespace called "monitoring". This is the first time I'm setting anything up outside of the default namespace as well, not sure if that is a factor.

### Edit

I'm using MicroK8s on my home Ubuntu machine. It's a single-node cluster, "bare metal" in that it's running on the host OS, not a VM.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: Added the answer.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Could you attach also version (f.e. `microk8s ctr version`)?